# Is it just me, or is the [data] tag a bit silly?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Maybe it's just me, but I think using [data](/questions/tagged/data) as a tag doesn't add that much information. But still there are [3711 questions labeled with this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data?sort=newest&pagesize=50).

Do we really need the [data](/questions/tagged/data) tag or can we safely burninate it?

Comment: @Gamecat: I think that this question should be generalized for "overly broad tags".  For example, the `api` tag on StackOverflow is pretty much worthless and I remove it almost everywhere I see it (especially if there is a more specific tag).

Comment: @casparOne,  I completely agree. Tags should be keywords that can be used to filter questions.

Comment: Maybe those questions are requests for getting tons of data. `:-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess in theory there are questions that involve quantities of data as a notable aspect of the topic. I can understand why it was created. (But even then, I'd expect a [data-handling](/questions/tagged/data-handling), if anything, to be the name of the game.)

But certainly, in practice, I can't see any more merit in a [data](/questions/tagged/data) tag on SO than in a [computers](/questions/tagged/computers) tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree. The instances of [data](/questions/tagged/data) should be removed in most of those instances. Some, like "How to merge lines of CSV in PHP" might be tagged [data-processing](/questions/tagged/data-processing), or maybe some similar tags, but they're all wrong where they are and completely vague.